# Why when I paste lines from one layer to another, their length changes?

Tags: qgis

I have a project. And I need the total length of the lines in one vector layer. I use sum line length and statistics and they both have the same length.
I paste the lines into another layer, and the total length changes. And I don't know why!
I have the same projection in all layers.
And I don't know which one is correct.
The change is about 1m in 1km!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Providing screenshots and sample data for testing is always a good idea. With the information you provided, it's almost impossible to guess what went wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works